# Creating Oracle View with using a Composite key table

Tags: oracle, view, oracle11g, composite-key

I am looking into creating a view that holds details for movies. I have to select The category name and id's, Number of films in each category and the average rental rate of each category.
The problem is that I am uncertain how to to this using the composite table in the middle. I have problem matching the average "rental_rate" with the category.name. I have used allot of code to make this work but this is my my version I came closest to, aswell as the table layout I used:

```
SELECT category_id, category.name, COUNT(category.film), AVG(rental_rate)
  FROM film_category 
  FULL OUTER JOIN category USING (film_category.category_id)
  FULL OUTER JOIN film USING (film_category.film_id)
  GROUP BY category_id;
```

[image: Table mapping for problem.]

Error I am currently Getting:
(category.name) is not a group function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add category.name into GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT category_id, category.name, COUNT(category.film), AVG(rental_rate)
  FROM film_category 
  FULL OUTER JOIN category USING (film_category.category_id)
  FULL OUTER JOIN film USING (film_category.film_id)
  GROUP BY category_id, category.name;
```

Comment: Can you explain why I need category.name. This is just for future users.

Comment: All columns without analytic functions from select clause should be repeated in GROUP BY. Please find more information about this on http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.1.0/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html. I appreciate very much psoug.org's blog - http://psoug.org/library.html